# In Crystal Reports 2013 when "ALL" chosen in parameters I get no results at all

Tags: crystal-reports

Choosing All from a parameter option in a crosstab reports returns no records but I can get results when individual customer names is chosen in the parameter
In the selection parameters I have :

```
IF {?CustName} <> "(ALL)" THEN {MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME} = {? CustName}   ELSE TRUE and
IF {?Facility} <> "(ALL)" THEN {MW_SALES_DETAIL.FACILITY} = {?Facility} ELSE TRUE and
IF {?GroupBy} = "Monthly" then true 
and{MW_SALES_DETAIL.ACTIVITYDATE} in ({?Start Date} to {?End Date}) and
IF {?BilledStatus}= "Billed" then {MW_SALES_DETAIL.BILLSTATUS} >"2" else 
IF {?BilledStatus} = "Not Billed" then {MW_SALES_DETAIL.BILLSTATUS} <"3"
else  
if{?GroupBy} = "Weekly" then true and
IF {?CustName} <> "(ALL)" THEN {MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME} = {?CustName}     ELSE TRUE and
IF {?Facility} <> "(ALL)" THEN {MW_SALES_DETAIL.FACILITY} = {?Facility} ELSE TRUE and
{MW_SALES_DETAIL.ACTIVITYDATE} in ({?Start Date} to {?End Date}) and
IF {?BilledStatus}= "Billed" then {MW_SALES_DETAIL.BILLSTATUS} >"2" else 
IF {?BilledStatus} = "Not Billed" then {MW_SALES_DETAIL.BILLSTATUS} <"3"
```

Everything seems to work except when I choose "ALL"  for the customer name - it seems to be taking the all selection as a literal as when I show the query it dispays as :

```
Select    
 "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."FACILITY", "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."BILLEDAMT", "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."DESCR", "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."GLACCT", "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."NAME", "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."ACTIVITYDATE", "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."BILLSTATUS"FROM "ALPS"."MW_SALES_DETAIL""MW_SALES_DETAIL"WHERE  "MW_SALES_DETAIL"."NAME"='ALL'
```

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In else case instead of `True` try like below:

```
IF {?CustName} <> "(ALL)" THEN {MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME} = {? CustName}   
ELSE {MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME}={MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME}
```

Comment: unfortunately no difference

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a solution  in the parameter I changed ALL to "ALL" and
I changed the select formula to be :
    IF {?CustName} > "(ALL)" THEN {MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME} = {?CustName} ELSE {MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME} like "*"  and

Answer (score -1):

You may need to explain in words what you are trying to achieve, but i've interpreted based on your formula... Here is how i'd write it;

```
(
 {?CustName} = "ALL" 
 or {MW_SALES_DETAIL.NAME} = {?CustName}
)
and (
 {?Facility} = "ALL" 
 or {MW_SALES_DETAIL.FACILITY} = {?Facility} 
)
and {MW_SALES_DETAIL.ACTIVITYDATE} >= {?Start Date} 
and {MW_SALES_DETAIL.ACTIVITYDATE} <= {?End Date}
and (
 (
  {?BilledStatus} = "Billed" 
  and {MW_SALES_DETAIL.BILLSTATUS} > 2
 )
 or ( 
  {?BilledStatus} = "Not Billed" 
  and {MW_SALES_DETAIL.BILLSTATUS} < 3
 )
)
```